# Django get coupon code and check the boolean value ("is available") in another column for that code

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

I currently have a model for coupon codes that looks like this

```
[code_number | code_available]

class CouponCode(models.Model):
    code_number = models.CharField(max_length=256,default='')
    code_available = models.BooleanField()
```

And I'm using Ajax to send a request to the server to see if the code is still available.

```
var couponCode = document.getElementById('id_coupon').value;

$.ajax({
  url: '/ajax/validate_coupon_code/',
  data: {
    'coupon_code': couponCode
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data) {
    if (data.is_available) {
      alert("Coupon code is available.");
    } else {
      alert("not available")
    }
  }
});
```

Right now, my code checks and returns whether the coupon code exists.

```
def validate_coupon_code(request):
    coupon_code = request.GET.get('coupon_code', None)
    data = {
        'is_available': CouponCode.objects.filter(code_number=coupon_code).exists(),  # code number
        'is_bool': CouponCode.objects.filter(code_number=True).exists()  # boolean column
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

But I am trying to get the coupon code and check the corresponding field in the `code_available` column to see if it is still set to `True` and then return that.

I feel like I'm close but can't seem to get it.

Note 1: the `is_bool` part is where I was trying to make this work

Note 2: I am aware that the Ajax if statement is checking the `data.is_available` I was using print statements to check the boolean value in the Python code.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

CouponCode.objects.get(code_number=coupon_code).code_available

Using [get](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#get) instead of [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#filter) is better is this case, because get returns the object and filter a queryset. I imagine that code_number will be like a Primary Key in your case. And, for what I understand, queryset is used when you don't know how many objects will be returned from the query.

Comment: Hero. Could you explain to me whats going on here? i get that i am first looking for the code, but what does [0] do and i assume that .code_available is just saying "hey get the field code_available for this coupon code"?

Comment: I've edited my answer since I imagine that will be just one coupon with a given code_number. So, you could just load the object with get (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#get) and it will raise an error if there is more than one coupon with the given code_number